# Database is locked error in SQLite in iOS while inserting or updating?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have a CITIES table in which I store the city name and date for the same.Now for every transaction like INSERT , UPDATE it gets executed successfully for the first time.However on second attempt I get a error saying **database is locked error**.Where am I missing the close and/or finalize  , I don't seem to understand.The confusion is due to the use of nested queries where the `update/insert` query is dependent upon result from `count` query. The flow of code is as follows.

1] Reading the database /Rerieving the data is done.

2]Once data is displayed in `ORDER BY DATE` way.Selection from table for a newCity or existing City is done .

3]This calls for 'viewDataBaseForCity' method, in which update or insert is done.

4]Again reading from database is done.

```
     //Retrieve data
-(NSMutableArray *)getCities{

const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

@try {

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &citiesDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT cityname FROM CITIES ORDER BY modifieddate DESC"];

        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(citiesDB,
                               query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                  (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                [resultArray addObject:name];

            }
            sqlite3_reset(statement);
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            return resultArray;
        }

    }

}
@catch (NSException *exception) {

    NSLog(@"SQL ERROR : %@",[exception reason]);

}
@finally {


    sqlite3_close(citiesDB);

  }
  return nil;

}




 //save our data

-(void)viewDataBaseForCity:(NSString *)cityName addedDate:(NSString *)dateAdded{

modifiedDate = dateAdded;
recentCity = cityName;
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

@try {

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &citiesDB)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT COUNT(CITYNAME) FROM CITIES WHERE CITYNAME ='%@'", cityName];
        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(citiesDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL)!= SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open database");
            NSLog(@"%s Prepare failure '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(citiesDB), sqlite3_errcode(citiesDB));

        }else{

            if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                int count = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
                NSLog(@"Found city count is : %d",count);
                if (count==0) {
                    //insert
                    [self insertNewCity];

                }else{
                    //update
                    [self updateCities];

                }
             sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            }else{
                NSLog(@"Not Found");
            }


        }


    }

}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"SQlite exception : %@",[exception reason]);
}
@finally {
    sqlite3_close(citiesDB);

}

}

//Insert

-(void)insertNewCity{
   NSString *insert_sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO CITIES(cityname,modifieddate)VALUES (\'%@\',\'%@\')",recentCity,modifiedDate];

  const char *insert_stmt = [insert_sql UTF8String];
  sqlite3_prepare_v2(citiesDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
  if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE)
  {
     NSLog(@"Insert Successfull");
     NSLog(@"SQLite Entry for Cities: %s and Time : %s", sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0),sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1));

  }
  else{
     NSLog(@"Insert Failed");
     NSLog(@"%s Prepare failure '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(citiesDB), sqlite3_errcode(citiesDB));

  }
   sqlite3_finalize(statement);

 }

 //Update
 -(void)updateCities{

   NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE CITIES set modifieddate ='%@' WHERE cityname='%@'", modifiedDate, recentCity];
   NSLog(@"Update Query : %@",querySQL);
   const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
   if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(citiesDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
   {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE){
        NSLog(@"updated successfully");

    }else{

          NSLog(@"%s Update failure '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(citiesDB), sqlite3_errcode(citiesDB));
     }
     sqlite3_finalize(statement);


   }


 }
```

Comment: You aren't closing the database access.

Comment: I am doing that in finally.Isn't that enough? Because in `viewDataBaseForCity` I am opening database once so closing it in finally.

Comment: You are not doing it at the right line, silly.

Comment: Can you suggest where to close?

Comment: Your "COUNT" query is not finalized (until too late).

Comment: There is no need to close the DB between queries.  It can be left open for hours.  It's normal to open the DB when the app starts and leave it open.

Comment: Where do you think should I finalise the count query?

Comment: Finalize it before you do another query.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by taking the count first, finalising the transaction, then deciding whether to update or delete.

```
-(void)viewDataBaseForCity:(NSString *)cityName addedDate:(NSString *)dateAdded{

 int count =0;
 modifiedDate = dateAdded;
 recentCity = cityName;
 const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

 @try {

 if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &citiesDB)==SQLITE_OK)
 {
     NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT COUNT(CITYNAME) FROM CITIES WHERE CITYNAME ='%@'", cityName];
     const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
     if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(citiesDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL)!= SQLITE_OK)
     {
         NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open database");
         NSLog(@"%s Prepare failure '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(citiesDB), sqlite3_errcode(citiesDB));

     }else{


         if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
         {
             count = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
             NSLog(@"Found city count is : %d",count);

         }else{
             NSLog(@"Not Found");
         }

         sqlite3_finalize(statement);

     }


 }

 if (count==0) {
     //insert
     [self insertNewCity];

 }else{
     //update
     [self updateCities];

 }




}
 @catch (NSException *exception) {
     NSLog(@"SQlite exception : %@",[exception reason]);
 }
 @finally {

     sqlite3_close(citiesDB);

 }

}
```